# MapKit center userLocation in view

Tags: ios, mapkit, core-location

Using MapKit (iOS 7), when you zoom to the userLocation it will place that location in the center of the "visible portion" of the mapView.

```
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation
   {
      MKCoordinateRegion mapRegion;
      mapRegion.center = mapView.userLocation.coordinate;
      mapRegion.span.latitudeDelta = 0.2;
      mapRegion.span.longitudeDelta = 0.2;
     [mapView setRegion:mapRegion animated: YES];
   }
```

This means if you have a navigation bar that it will consider the center to be:

```
   CGFloat y = (self.mapView.bounds.size.height - self.navigationController.navigationBar.bounds.size.height) / 2.0;
   CGFloat x = self.mapView.bounds.size.width / 2.0;
   CGPoint userLocationPoint = CGPointMake(x, y);
```

The same is true for the statusBar, toolbars, etc... I can see how this would be advantageous but I'd prefer to not have it in my app. Is there a way to tell the mapView to disregard these insets?

Comment: What you are trying to ask is not very clear.... how is center of the map view related to navigation or status bar's center?

Comment: I'm having this problem as we speak. What HCHogan is saying is that, even if the map view spans the full width and height of the view, the center where the user location annotation shows is slightly lower than it should be, shifted by the position of the nav bar and the status bar.

Did you ever figure out how to fix this?

Comment: Yeah, I just calculated the offset of where I wanted the point to be vs where it was being rendered. First in CLLocationDegrees, then convert to points. Calculate a new region using the current span and then set it on the mapView. I'll post an answer here with code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this by calculating the offset I desire and setting a new region.

```
// Update iVar when region changes
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionDidChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated{
    CGFloat screenHeight = self.view.frame.size.height;
    CGFloat otherControlsHeight = self.toolbarView.frame.size.height + self.collectionView.frame.size.height + self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height;
    CGFloat pointOffset = (screenHeight - otherControlsHeight);
    CGFloat percentage = pointOffset / screenHeight;
    latitudeOffset = mapView.region.span.latitudeDelta / 2.0 * percentage;

}


// Then whenever you set your centerCoordinate or region
MKCoordinateRegion region = self.mapView.region;
region.center = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(region.center.latitude - latitudeOffset, region.center.longitude);
[self.mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
```